# Get user wall feed posts with custom filter using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In the Facebook Graph API I am able to retrieve the user's wall feed using the following:

`/me/feed`

And it returns all feeds from the user's wall, however I want to filter this, I want to get everything except likes.
I noticed that the feed type for likes is `link` and the stuff I need is something like `status` and `photo`.
So how do I get every feed except the ones that have the type `link` and how do I get every feed that has the type `status`?

Something like:
`/me/feed?type!=link`
and
`/me/feed?type=status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gathered, if you want to filter the data you retrieve in your own way, the way to go is to use `FQL`, since the `Graph API` is somewhat limited.
Since I'm not sure if I can do what I wanted with the `Graph API`, but the info I gathered lead me to believe I can't, I'm marking `FQL` as my answer.

Comment: Since FQL has been deprecated - it's not an option anymore, unfortunately.